Can't get permissions to open files on hard drive
I'm new to Ubuntu with a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 having 3 SSD hard drives inside the PC, one with the operating system with which I don't have any troubles, and the other two with files. For example I can't open a file with gimp from those 2 hard drives. It ends with:
Error opening directory 
'/mnt/fe90c49b-4393-42b9-98f3-b529e86a7d8b/Midjourney's images/Inspiration Photo/Masks': 
Permission denied

In the same time, I was able to save path for both hard drives for comfyui app to access files without problems, but if I want to save an image from Discord, I can only save it to my system hard drive as it's impossible to save it on the other one.
Could not read the content of folder, 
error opening directory /mnt/>>>>>>> permission denied

I set all permissions to read and write.

Try: sudo chmod -Rf 744 /mnt

i tried
ls -l /mnt
total 144
drwxrwxrwx  9 theduc theduc  12288 Oct 29 19:20 8bc34d79-424b-47e7-b3b5-b10a3a8e9155
drwxrwxrwx 10 theduc theduc   4096 Nov 25 23:31 fe90c49b-4393-42b9-98f3-b529e86a7d8b
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   131072 Nov 26 16:51 usb-Seagate_M3_Portable_NM156E0Q-0:0-part1
that's already my permission state , with which i can't save image from discord or gimp
i may be wrong but if some app are installed thru flatpak does it influence on their way to handle some files after....like limiting access to some files ...

i tried the "sudo chmod -Rf 744 /mnt"
i can save image from discordt o my sytem hard drive (root) but still impossible on the 2 other internal hard drive.
also even if files window shows my 2 other external hard drives connected thru usb , they aren't able , aren't showing on a save image window from discord

i tried it now i can't access anymore permissions on both hard drives and even open them in files return: could not Display , the file is an unknown type

If they are non-Linux file systems, they do not support permissions and must be repaired with the original applications of the operating system to which they belong.

i was able to repair permissions . i don't understand those 2 SSD were working perfectly with fedora 40 before i decide to go for ubuntu , i didn't change their hardware connection or nothing and i was able to save some download files on all of them

find out on another forum what the pb was .
It was an app permission pbs not drive one.
Check if your app as the removavle-media option, if it's active and activate it if not with thie CLI:
My pbs were with gimp, discord and chromium so i did the same for the 3 apps and show the command for gimp:
snap connections gimp | grep removable
